# How does the squeeze function in the NaCl Poly1305 implementation work?

Tags: mac, modular-arithmetic, poly1305

The NaCl `ref` implementation of the Poly1305 algorithm uses the following reduction function (which is called `squeeze()`):

```
static void squeeze(unsigned int h[17])
{
    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int u;
    u = 0;
    for (j = 0;j < 16;++j) { u += h[j]; h[j] = u & 255; u >>= 8; }
    u += h[16]; h[16] = u & 3;
    u = 5 * (u >> 2);
    for (j = 0;j < 16;++j) { u += h[j]; h[j] = u & 255; u >>= 8; }
    u += h[16]; h[16] = u;
}
```

I understand globally what is done in the first for loop, namely that each integer in h is reduced to 256 bits, with the carry being carried over to the next integer. I only don't grasp what happens from the `h[16] = u & 3;` on. Where does the `u & 3;` come from? and the `u = 5 * (u >> 2);`?

Also, if I would want to change the radix here, say from 2^8 bits to 2^16, would that require me to change the above mentioned fragments? I would need to change al the 8's to 16, and the 255's to 2^16-1, but would that be it?

Does anyone know how this `squeeze` function works, and provide an explanation, as well as an answer to my second question?

The implementation itself provides no documentation, and the answer on [How does NaCl Poly1305 implementation do modular multiplication?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9222/how-does-nacl-poly1305-implementation-do-modular-multiplication) does not delve into the squeeze function. See this stackexchange question for the full code.

Comment: Hint: $2^{130} \equiv 5 \pmod p$, so $2^{130} x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \equiv 5 x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \pmod p$.

Comment: @Swueamish Ossifrage Thanks! But how does that explain the u & 3 and (u >> 2) ?

Comment: @Peter The number is $x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \cdots + 2^{128} h[16]$.  We want to break it into $x = x_{\mathrm{lo}} + 2^{130} x_{\mathrm{hi}}$.  How do you get $x_{\mathrm{hi}}$ in terms of the $h[i]$?

Comment: @Squeamish Ossifrage I'm sorry, but I don't understand the whole idea of the x_hi and x_lo, and how this relates to the AND and the >> parts I didn't understand? Would you mind explaining this a little more in an answer? Thank you very much

Comment: Read $x_{\mathrm{lo}}$ as $x \mathbin\& (2^{130} - 1)$, _i.e._ the low 130 bits of $x$, and $x_{\mathrm{hi}}$ as $x \mathbin\gg 130$, _i.e._ the bits above the low 130 bits.  If you want to recombine them, you compute $(x_{\mathrm{hi}} \mathbin\ll 130) \mathbin| x_{\mathrm{lo}}$, which is the same as $2^{130} x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}}$.  But here $x$ is spread across multiple digits: $h[0]$ is bits 0-7, $h[1]$ is bits 8-15, _etc._, and $h[16]$ is bits 128-135 (ignoring wider digits with delayed carries as Poly1305 uses).  So how do you get $x_{\mathrm{hi}}$ from $h$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ideas going on here:

1. Radix 256 arithmetic with delayed carries.

   Here we represent an integer $x$ by $x_0 + 2^8 x_1 + 2^{16} x_2 + \dots + 2^{128} x_{16}$.  In canonical form, the digits $x_i$ lie in $\{0,1,2,\dots,255\}$, but in the Poly1305 computation, we delay the propagation of carries as long as we reliably can in order to save computation, so the $x_i$ might be larger, giving multiple possible representations for each integer $x$ in this form.
2. Poly1305 reduction $2^{130} x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \equiv 5 x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \pmod p$.

   We are working modulo $p = 2^{130} - 5$, which has $2^{130} - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and so $2^{130} \equiv 5 \pmod p$.  The idea is that if we have an integer $x$, we can take its 130 low bits $x_{\mathrm{lo}} = x \mathbin\& (2^{130} - 1)$, and the high bits $x_{\mathrm{hi}} = x \mathbin\gg 130$, so that $$x = (x_{\mathrm{hi}} \ll 130) \mathbin| x_{\mathrm{lo}} = 2^{130} x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}},$$ and then do a reduction step by computing $$x \equiv 5x_{\mathrm{hi}} + x_{\mathrm{lo}} \pmod p;$$ *i.e.*, shift/multiply/add.

The two ideas are done simultaneously.  I recommend that you try to work through it yourself from those two ideas, but—**spoiler alert!**—here's the full gory details if you're still completely stuck:

---

```
static void squeeze(unsigned h[17])
```

On entry, $h$ represents an integer $x$ in radix 256, with digits that may exceed 255 because of delayed carries, as long as they have some bound $B$ so the carries aren't too excessive.

$x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + 2^{16} h[2] + \dots + 2^{128} h[16] \\
h[0], h[1], \dots, h[16] < B$

First, we propagate all the delayed carries and bound each digit by the radix up to 128 bits:

```
u = 0;
for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
```

- Loop invariants:

  $x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{8j} (h[j] + u) + \dots + 2^{128} h[16] \\
  h[0], h[1], \dots, h[j] < 256 \\
  h[j + 1], \dots, h[16] < B$

```
    { u += h[j]; h[j] = u & 255; u >>= 8; }
```

Now $h[0], \dots, h[15]$ are reduced, leaving us with $h[16]$ and a 128-bit carry.  We'll go two bits further to get a 130-bit carry:

$x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{128} (h[16] + u) \\
h[0], h[1], \dots, h[15] < 256 \\
h[16] < B$

```
u += h[16]; h[16] = u & 3;
```

Now note that $2^{130} \equiv 5 \pmod p$.  So—after we shift $u \gg 2$ below—when we have

$x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{128} h[16] + 2^{130} u \\
h[0], h[1], \dots, h[15] < 256 \\
h[16] < 4$

we can reduce $x = h[0] + \dots + 2^{130} u \equiv h[0] + \dots + 5 u \pmod p$.

```
u = 5 * (u >> 2);
```

Now we can add $5 u$ starting at the first digit, and propagate the carries:

$x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{128} h[16] + 5 u \\
h[0], h[1], \dots, h[15] < 256 \\
h[16] < 4$

```
for (j = 0;j < 16;++j)
```

- Loop invariants:

  $x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{8j} (h[j] + u) + \dots + 2^{128} h[16] \\
  h[0], h[1], \dots, h[15] < 256 \\
  h[16] < 4$

```
    { u += h[j]; h[j] = u & 255; u >>= 8; }
```

Now we have a 128-bit carry again, but there's plenty of room because $h[16]$ is only two bits at this point, from the above `h[16] = (u & 3)`.

$x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{128} (h[16] + u)
h[0], h[1], \dots, h[15] < 256 \\
h[16] < 4$

```
u += h[16]; h[16] = u;
```

Finally, $h$ again represents an integer in radix 256, with digits that are bounded by the radix:

$x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + \dots + 2^{128} h[16] \\
h[0], h[1], \dots, h[16] < 256$

However, it is not necessarily the *least* representative modulo $p$.  For that, we need to `freeze`; `squeeze` just propagates a batch of delayed carries and does a single reduction step so there's room for more arithmetic.

(Figuring out what $B$ is and setting corresponding bounds on the carry $u$ in each step left as an exercise for the reader.)

---

> Also, if I would want to change the radix here, say from 2^8 bits to 2^16, would that require me to change the above mentioned fragments? I would need to change al the 8's to 16, and the 255's to 2^16-1, but would that be it?

The array $h$ represents the integer $x = h[0] + 2^8 h[1] + 2^{16} h[2] + \dots + 2^{128} h[16]$ on entry, and $x - (2^{130} - 5) k$ for some $k \geq 0$ on exit after the reduction step where we replace $2^{130} u$ by $5 u$.  (Casting out $2^{130} - 5$'s.)

If you want to change the radix, say from $2^8$ to $2^{17}$, then the array $h$ will instead represent $x = h[0] + 2^{17} h[1] + 2^{34} h[2] + \dots + 2^{119} h[7] + 2^{136} h[8]$.  The goal is to compute the same reduction, $x - (2^{130} - 5) k$ for some $k \geq 0$, but finding multiples of $2^{130}$ to replace by multiples of $5$ for the reduction step will happen at a different *digit* position, $h[i]$, and a different *bit* position within that digit or carry, $u \gg j$.

It is an easy exercise to find these positions.  For a simpler exercise, you could try writing arithmetic modulo $2^{31} - 1$ in radix $2^8$, in which you can easily exhaustively test a reduction step for correctness.  I recommend that you carry out this exercise rather than asking pseudonymous strangers on the internet to spoon-feed you answers!